# Mongoose - Only count certain documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I'm currently coding a Discord bot, and I'm trying to count every document within a model based on an object.
Simply put, I want to count every document that has ID: 1 and exclude everything else.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoose `find()` method.

```
model.find({id: 1}).then(data => console.log(data.length)).catch(err => ...)
```

The data will be an array of documents with ID =  1 and the log will return number of documents.